# For attributes in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a for statement that contains all the check box's that are in my list. For example this code displays the following

```
Select
Tree
Cat
Dog
```

Where each of select Tree Cat and Dog all have a check box associated with it.

What I am trying to figure out is how I can know if for example Tree has been selected. Since what I am trying to do is create a link that contains all of the box's that have been checked. For example if tree and dog  was checked off I would do:

```
var link;

if(document.getElementById("checklistNone").checked)
    link += document.getElementById("checklistNone").value;
```

Expected output:

```
treeDog
```

Unfortunately the method of coding I did above did not work out. I do not know exactly how to work with the for statement in this case in html to see which is exactly checked off and to retrieve that value.

```
<ul class="filter" id="checklist">
    <li><label for="checklistSelect" onMouseOver="mouseOver()" onMouseOut="mouseOut()">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checklistSelect" checked="true" disabled="true" onClick="selectCheck(this)"/>
        Select
    </label></li>
    <li><label id="none" for="checklistNone" onMouseOver="mouseOver()" onMouseOut="mouseOut()">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checklistNone" checked="true" disabled="true" onChange="filter()"/>
        none
    </label></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to avoid the use of jQuery in this project, therefore I am aiming to just use java, javascript, and html in my jsp.

Comment: Java would probably be a really bad idea :)

Comment: I've noticed that this question has a the Java tag, please remove this tag as this question has nothing to do with Java, for more info on the differences read this; http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml

Comment: Show your real code, a minimal example that demonstrates what you are actually doing. In the code posted, there is no attempt at writing any loop, and in the markup, there’s no Cat or Dog.

Comment: Where is the values `Tree` `Cat` `Dog` etc in the sample `html`? How are those words related to the checkboxes in sample? please update the question properly...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to undertsant what you want, and I made a little jsFiddle (run with openned console ^^) :

http://jsfiddle.net/cpase8wx/2/

I just used :

```
var res = "";
for (i = 0; i<4 ; i++) {
   console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("choice"));
   if (document.getElementsByClassName("choice")[i].checked)
   {
       res += document.getElementsByClassName("choice")[i].id + " ";
   }
}
console.log(res);
```